# Parsing a JSON in Flutter from an API that returns only 50 results at a time

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been working on using the Nutritionix API in a Flutter app.  Nutritionix only returns 50 results at a time with their API and from talking to them (our group has a plan set up with them), the only way to deal with it is to code around it.  I'm still very much learning on the fly how to best deal with making API calls and parsing JSON files while trying to grasp Dart/Flutter.  My current strategy was to try to make an upfront call to the API to get the total number of listings a particular restaurant has.

From my nutritionixCall.dart file:

```
static Resource<int> getTotalNum (String restaurant){
return Resource(
    url: 'https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/' + restaurant + '?results=0:50&fields=item_name,brand_name,nf_calories,nf_sodium,nf_sugars,nf_cholesterol,nf_total_fat,nf_dietary_fiber&appId=816cee15&appKey=API_KEY',
    parse: (response) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body);

      return result['total_hits'];
    }
);
```

}

Then the thinking was I could load the total number into a subsequent call back to the API, and keep calling the API in increments of 50 to populate a list.  This has not surprisingly failed miserably, just causing the emulator to stall when I try to call it.

From my nutritionixList.dart file:

```
for (int i =0; i <= totalListings; i+51) {
   Webservice().load(NutritionixData.get(restaurant, category, i)).then((
       nutritionListings) =>
   {


     setState(() =>
     {
       _nutritionixData += _nutritionixData + nutritionListings
     })
   });
 }
```

}

From my nutritionixCall.dart file:

```
static Resource<List<NutritionixData>> get (String restaurant, String category, int minResults) {


final nutritionalIncrement = 50;
int maxResults = minResults + nutritionalIncrement;





return Resource(
    url: 'https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/' + restaurant + '?results='+ minResults.toString() + ':' + maxResults.toString() + '&fields=item_name,brand_name,nf_calories,nf_sodium,nf_sugars,nf_cholesterol,nf_total_fat,nf_dietary_fiber&appId=',
    parse: (response) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body);
      Iterable list = result['hits'];





      list = list.map((model) => NutritionixData.fromJson(model)).toList();

      return list.where((f) => f.nutritionFields.nfCategory.contains(category)).toList();
    }
);
```

}

If anyone has any experience with sequencing through an API that only returns a small set of results on each query with Flutter I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: here some tutorial https://www.initpals.com/flutter/how-to-lazy-load-large-list-from-http-rest-api-with-pagination-in-flutter/ it might help you,i have used in my project

Comment: @wnjl Could you please share the model class for this? I am having trouble building it.

Comment: @who-aditya-nawandar Would you mind e-mailing me at nick dot langan at gmail dot com?  I'd be happy to share there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to process all results from the API immediately, or just show them to the user when they scroll through a display? If it is the latter, then you should not load all the data immediately, but lazily load the data as the user scrolls.

For the latter I found this example: https://www.initpals.com/flutter/how-to-lazy-load-large-list-from-http-rest-api-with-pagination-in-flutter/. (Warning: I have not tried it, so cannot warrant for the quality.)

Comment: This very well could work.  My only reason to process the results from the API immediately is I am placing the results in certain buckets ("Entrees, "Sides", "Beverages).  So I wanted to get everything up front and then place the items in their respective categories based on a basic algorithm I have, THEN return the values to the user in the category lists.

Comment: What is the order of items in the display, because this is the order that you want to retrieve the items. If the display is in categories, then you should load the first chunk of the first category. If the API supports filtering by category, then this is straightforward. If it does no then you have to retrieve items, applying your category logic on the retrieved items, until you get enough of the correct category - you do not need to load them all.